# How to remove columns from ArrayList or GridView c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, datagridview

Is there any way to remove "columns" from an ArrayList?

I got this site up and running before attempting populating my DropDownLists from txt files so I hard-typed each value in. Now I've made an ArrayList from each DropDownList so I can display those lists in DataGridView on the site. The only issue is that "Enabled" and "Selected" show up as columns and I cannot seem to remove the column in the ArrayList, or specify which columns to bring in when creating the ArrayList, or GridView using GridView.Columns.Remove(); because the integers 0 or 1 or 2 don't seem to correspond with anything and the site doesn't run and I can't specify a string as the column title for what to remove.

The DataGrids show up with columns as |**Enabled**|**Selected**|**Text**|**Value**|

Here's the code for this piece as it stands (You can see what I've tried out and that didn't work that I've commented away):

```
        // Create ListArrays from DropDownLists
        ArrayList BuildingList = new ArrayList(Building.Items);
        ArrayList DepartmentList = new ArrayList(Department.Items);
        //Building.Items.Remove("Enabled");
        //Building.Items.Remove("Selected");

        // Populate Building GridView
        BuildingGrid.DataSource = BuildingList;
        BuildingGrid.DataBind();
        //BuildingGrid.Columns.Remove;
        //BuildingGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;

        // Populate Department GridView
        DepartmentGrid.DataSource = DepartmentList;
        DepartmentGrid.DataBind();
        //DepartmentGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        //DepartmentGrid.Columns[1].Visible = false;
```

I would just go ahead and create a simple 2d array in a txt file with fields for "Value" and "Text" so the DropDownList will pull it in properly, but I can't figure that out either without being terribly inefficient and confusing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `DepartmentGrid.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no (I forgot to put that in with comment). Getting pushback "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: I suggest you to bind the datasources to a collection instead of an ArrayList and to use the `[Browsable(false)]` attribute to the properties you want to hide

Comment: I believe that DropDownList items are a collection, they just include the boolean values for "enabled" and "selected", right?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the solution I ended up at. I finally figured out how to extract everything from a txt file, and place it into the grid the way I wanted to.

```
        // Populate Department GridView
        // get all lines of csv file
        string[] BuildingString = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Content/BuildingsCSV.csv"));
        string[] DepartmentString = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("Content/DepartmentsCSV.csv"));
        // create new datatable
        DataTable BuildingTable = new DataTable();
        DataTable DepartmentTable = new DataTable();

        // Building Table
        // get the column header means first line
        string[] tempbuild = BuildingString[0].Split(',');
        // creates columns of gridview as per the header name
        foreach (string t in tempbuild)
        {
            BuildingTable.Columns.Add(t, typeof(string));
        }
        // now retrive the record from second line and add it to datatable
        for (int i = 1; i < BuildingString.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] t = BuildingString[i].Split(',');
            BuildingTable.Rows.Add(t);
        }
        // Department Table
        // get the column header means first line
        string[] tempdept = DepartmentString[0].Split(',');
        // creates columns of gridview as per the header name
        foreach (string t in tempdept)
        {
            DepartmentTable.Columns.Add(t, typeof(string));
        }
        // now retrive the record from second line and add it to datatable
        for (int i = 1; i < DepartmentString.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] t = DepartmentString[i].Split(',');
            DepartmentTable.Rows.Add(t);
        }
        // assign gridview datasource property by datatable
        BuildingGrid.DataSource = BuildingTable;
        BuildingGrid.DataBind();
        BuildingGrid.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        DepartmentGrid.DataSource = DepartmentTable;
        DepartmentGrid.DataBind();
        DepartmentGrid.Rows[0].Visible = false;

        foreach (DataRow drb in BuildingTable.Rows)
        {
            BuildingDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem(drb[0].ToString(), drb[1].ToString()));
        }
        foreach (DataRow drd in DepartmentTable.Rows)
        {
            DepartmentDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem(drd[0].ToString(), drd[1].ToString()));
        }
```